# Architecture of distributed tasks execution with priorities

Tags: rabbitmq, akka, distributed-computing, amazon-sqs, amazon-swf

We are looking into creating a **distributed system for task execution**, where the tasks have **priorities** in .NET (C#). There are a lot of options, I would like to get your take on it. The options & their disadvantages are:

1) **Amazon's SWF** (Simple WorkFlow) - in .NET we can't use a framework such as java's FLOW which simplifies. this means a lot of boilerplate code. In addition, this offering from amazon doesn't seem to be very popular (so: no community support, and might eventually disappear)

2) Building our own on top of a queuing system

2.a) **SQS** - not really a FIFO, and using 2 queues (normal and high priority) won't give us granular control over the priorities (we might be able to live with that)

2.b) **RabbitMQ** - administrative overhead (setting it up, configuring it in cluster mode for reliability, etc)

3) I have received another suggestion to use "event driven" without queues. I can't see how it's possible, maybe someone can help clarify it to me? (oh, and, is it related to a technology called **Akka** (actor based))

Thank you

Comment: I'm using SWF with .Net for about two years, and I don't regret the decision. Flow framework is nice, and I do envy some of its capabilities, but C# also has its strengths. SWF is pretty simple, at its core. I've implemented simple wrappers for what I needed, and found it quite flexible. For example, I'm implemented retries to failed activity tasks in just a two hours. It also integrates very well with CloudWatch.

Comment: probably SQS is the cheapest option in terms of effort required. From the Q is not really clear what the pattern of usage is going to be, but if it's just queueing up work and executing in order of priorities, using multiple SQS queues and going through them in order of priority totally makes sense. (you can make it as granular as you want)

Answer (score 0):

SQS is probably going to be the simplest - very little code is required, and the cost is extremely low and the setup time is minimal.

If 2 queues and hi/low priority is not enough then create 3 queues, or 5 queues or 10 queues - you can be as granular as you need to be.

You can have multiple worker machines scanning all the queues in priority in order, or have some machines just dedicated to processing the hi-priortiy queues, and these machines could be bigger/faster if you want to process even quicker.

Another option is to have seperate auto-scaling policies that will spin up more/faster machines based on a small increase in the length of the high-priority queues, but only scale up smaller/cheaper machines, when the low-priority queue gets very long....lots of options to choose from and fine-tune you solution.

Comment: Thanks for your input. After looking into all the solutions an idea that I didn't know about it's existence came through: service bus. (using NServiceBus or MassTransit). and then coordinate using Sagas. what do you think about that idea?